# Expected type 'Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface'. Found 'App\Model\Table\entity'

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.8, intelephense

I am not sure whether this is an issue with my code or intelephense, actually.

In my `UsersTable` I have a method that, given a `user_id`, fetches the user's data (through a call to another method) and makes a refound. Here is the code:

```
public function restoreBudget($userId)
{
    $user = $this->findUserData($userId);
    if ($user->subscription_plan->subscription_type == 'prepaid') {
        $user->credit = $user->credit + $user->price;
        $this->save($user);
    }
}

public function findUserData($id)
{
    $user = $this->find()
        ->contain(['SubscriptionPlans'])
        ->where([
            'Users.id' => $id
        ])
        ->first();

    return $user;
}
```

Now, everything seem to be working correctly, except that my IDE underlines the `$user` in `$this->save($user)`, and intelephense is pointing to this error:

`Expected type 'Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface'. Found 'App\Model\Table\entity'.`

Why is that? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When you point mouse over $user  "$user = $this->findUserData($userId);"  what is @var  type ???

Comment: It's `App\Model\Table\entity`. 
Fun fact, if I move the whole find into the `restoreBudget()` method (thus not calling an external method anymore), that warning disappears...

Comment: Bingo! You are right, there is a `* @return entity User` in the comment... removing it removes the warning too

Comment: Don't remove, change variable name , or add @var Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $user  in restoreBudget method

Comment: I have managed to fix it by replacing the return statement like this: `* @return \Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface User`